# Binding to attached behaviours

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a custom attached behaviour:

```
public static class CustomItemsBehaviour
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTestProperty =
     DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
         "MyTest",
         typeof(string),
         typeof(ItemsControl),
         new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

     public static string GetMyTest(ItemsControl itemsControl)
     {
        return (string)itemsControl.GetValue(MyTestProperty);
     }

     public static void SetMyTest(ItemsControl itemsControl, string value)
     {
        itemsControl.SetValue(MyTestProperty, value);
     }
}
```

I am trying to use it like so:

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" 
    AttachedBehaviours:CustomItemsBehaviour.MyTest="{Binding TestValue}">
```

But it fails with:

```
{"A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SetMyTest' property of type 'ListBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."}
```

I want to bind some value in my view model to the value of MyTest.  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your registration code. You should pass `typeof(CustomItemsBehaviour)` as owner type:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTestProperty =
 DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
     "MyTest",
     typeof(string),
     typeof(CustomItemsBehaviour),
     new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to acheive, but i think there is some mistakes in the declaration of your attached property. Try this :

```
public static class CustomItemsBehaviour
{
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTestProperty =
 DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
     "MyTest",
     typeof(string),
     typeof(CustomItemsBehaviour),
     new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

 public static string GetMyTest(DependencyObject itemsControl)
 {
    return (string)itemsControl.GetValue(MyTestProperty);
 }

 public static void SetMyTest(DependencyObject itemsControl, string value)
 {
    itemsControl.SetValue(MyTestProperty, value);
 }
```

}

See here [DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms597497%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)